# Find element by text and get the contents of the element after it

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find an element by text and get the contents of the element after it. The table will be changing depending on the user input so I can find nodes by counting down the table. And I'm not able to add class or id's to specific table elements in the application that I'm working with.

My attempt to find the element

```js
var firstnamefind = $(this).next().find("div:contains('First Name')").text();
$(".display").text(firstnamefind);
```

Html:

```html
    <table class="arm_profile_detail_tbl">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Neal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Parker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td>neal@email.com</td>
        </tr><tr><td>Phone Number</td>
        <td>9095551212</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Website (URL)</td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://website.com/" target="_blank">https://website.com/</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <div class="display">This should be the first name</div>
```

---

**How can I find specified element?**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dtq8bkr7/

Comment: Get the contents of the element after it?

Comment: Inside document.ready() `this` is the document which has no `next()`. Need a better explanation here since broken code is not a very good substitute for a properly detailed explanation of expected behavior. Also `:contains()` is case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
var firstnamefind = $(".arm_profile_detail_tbl td:contains('First Name')").text();
```

If you wanna get the next td (with the "Neal"), just use it

```
var firstnamefind = $(".arm_profile_detail_tbl td:contains('First Name')+td").text();
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks